# Spring SchedulingConfigurer retry-limit

Tags: java, spring, job-scheduling

Using a Spring SchedulingConfigurer implementation based on the below example, I would like to set a retry limit on my scheduled tasks.  If a job fails I would like to limit the number of times my scheduler attempts to run the task.  I'm looking for an annotation or configuration equivalent to `retry-limit="2"`.

Is it possible to set a retry-limit in a Spring SchedulingConfigurer?  If so, how could I accomplish that?

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledConfiguration implements SchedulingConfigurer {
    TaskScheduler taskScheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> job1;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> job2;
    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler =new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(10);// Set the pool of threads
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("scheduler-thread");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.initialize();
        job1(threadPoolTaskScheduler);// Assign the job1 to the scheduler
        // Assign the job1 to the scheduler
        this.taskScheduler=threadPoolTaskScheduler;// this will be used in later part of the article during refreshing the cron expression dynamically
        taskRegistrar.setTaskScheduler(threadPoolTaskScheduler);
    }
    private void job1(TaskScheduler scheduler) {
        job1 = scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " The Task1 executed at " + new Date());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Trigger() {
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                String cronExp = "0/5 * * * * ?";// Can be pulled from a db .
                return new CronTrigger(cronExp).nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }
    private void job2(TaskScheduler scheduler){
        job2=scheduler.schedule(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" The Task2 executed at "+ new Date());
            }
        }, new Trigger(){
            @Override
            public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                String cronExp="0/1 * * * * ?";//Can be pulled from a db . This will run every minute
                return new CronTrigger(cronExp).nextExecutionTime(triggerContext);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [Spring Retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) works with the scheduler. It's annotation-drivern.

Comment: Are you able to fix it? I have the same problem, Spring retry isnot working with schedular for me